# Electric Water: to replace or not to replace

Tags: water-heater

I have an electric hot water heater in my garage. It is a State Select and was installed around 2009. We moved into the house around 2012. Every 2 years I flush out the tank and replace the elements and also check the Anode Rod. The previous owner did not take care of it. I noticed rust on the very bottom of the tank. It appears to be surface rust, not a huge amount but not a small amount either. I live in FL and back in 2014 I noticed the pressure relief valve was malfunctioning causing water to collect in the bottom pan. I have since replaced it, but nevertheless, I believe there is residual rust from that on the tank. Should I replace it?

Comment: Would clean the rust off and probably give it a coat of paint.  Tank might last a few more years, but be ready to replace.  If you have the space for storage of a new tank, can have it ready.

Comment: It depends on your budget and tolerance of failure. We don't know your budget, and your tolerance for failure is entirely up to you. Most people don't replace major appliances until they've failed. Whether you should do so preventatively is _entirely_ up to you and a matter of opinion.

Comment: Although the rule of thumb is water heaters last about 10 years, they often last much longer than that, esp. with the kind of maintenance you are doing. I have a rental that I believe the WH is over 30 years old and is doing fine. It's a large one, 80 gal. if that makes a difference.  BTW, a question, why do you replace the elements every 2 years, they last a lot longer than that?

Comment: If you can *see the tank*, replace it. The tank should be factory-wrapped in thick layers of insulation.  The thermal losses with the tank being totally exposed are costing you enough electricity to buy another tanked heater.

Comment: When it starts leaking what happens?  worst case seems to be water on the floor of your garage, if that is going to be a disaster replace it before it starts leaking. if not you may as well use it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you replace it is a matter of opinion.
If you are of the ilk that wants to get the most out of an appliance and not spend what may be considered needless money, then no.
However if you are the nervous type and want to be assured that the tank is not likely to fail or leak and find comfort in spending money to feel secure then go ahead and replace it.
My opinion; If it makes the hot water I need and doesn't leak, I'm not replacing it.